# Unbreak my code - how to use function name as an argument in another function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have a few funtions for validation and I want to add events to every element in array.

```js
var items=[
    "metraz_od",
    "metraz_do",
    "cena_za_metr_od",
    "cena_za_metr_do",
    "cena_od",
    "cena_do",
    "pietro_min",
    "pietro_max",
    "rok_budowy_od",
    "rok_budowy_do",
    "ilosc_pieter_od",
    "ilosc_pieter_do",
    "minimalna_wysokosc"
];
var items_float=[
    "cena_tys"
];

function add_events(array, event, function_name){
    for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        (function(e){
            console.log("W funkcji "+array+" | "+event+" | "+function_name+" | ");
            document.getElementsByName(items[e])[0].addEventListener(event, function() {
            function_name(array[e]) 
            })
        })(i); 
    }
}



add_events(items,"keyup","validate_numb");
```

But it isn't working, propably because of using function name (string) as function argument (function add_events) - i think i can't do that :D

What can I do instad of?

EDIT: this is that function:

```js
function validate_numb(name){//argumentem jest nazwa pola
        var input = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
        var parsed_input = parseInt(input);//wartosc pola zamieniana na liczbe całkowitą
        if(isNaN(parsed_input) || parsed_input<0 || input!=parsed_input){
            document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value="";
            console.log("Validation of "+name+" failed");
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't this simply `function doSomething() {}` then `add_events(array, event, doSomething)` because then you're passing the reference to the function, and the `add_events` is executing that reference. Simple callback functions by the looks of it.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to pass it by string and not pass the function itself? Is some sort of dynamic lookup required? If so, where is the function located?

Comment: @squint I want to use only function name, because this function have a parameter which is an array (other argument in add_events) and that was my idea for that problem, propably stupid- i know :D

Comment: There are no stupid thoughts, just not asked questions. By the way, the title of your question brought this into my mind: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6eByMZJ9ueA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the function, not the function name. So:

`add_events(items,"keyup", validate_numb);` **- without quotes**

NOT

`add_events(items,"keyup", "validate_numb");`

Comment: still dont work, I added Edit with my function i using as an argument
now i wrote - add_events(items,"keyup",validate_numb);

Answer (score 1):

You can switch your

```
function_name(array[e])
```

with

```
window[function_name](array[e]))
```